# Panel without basepan but insulating sheet only.. long term problem?

Tags: electrical-panel

I'd like to know how common are these panels that don't use plastic basepan but has only insulating sheet between the chassis and the plug-in bus bar like the following:

[image]

(click to enlarge)

What are its long term problem for those who used it. Can these reddish insulating sheet tear?  What is it exactly made of?

My concern is one of the hot bus bar touching the metal chassis (in grey). What brands carry these just to see how it compares to those brands using the plastic basepan.

I'm thinking whether I should replace my main panel.

Answer (score 1):

The insulation is tough and if that is your only concern I would not replace a panel for this reason. Industrial panels have similar insulation on much larger panels think up to 3000 amps at 480 these are the largest panels I currently support and they are many years old and have never had an issue with the buss shorting out.